# How to customize my php echo code?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, if-statement

i echo some data in the Author Box of my Wordpress Theme with:

```
<?php echo $user_info->new_user_blond; ?> <?php echo $user_info->new_user_brown; ?> <?php echo $user_info->new_user_red; ?>
```

The users can check one ore more checkboxes. If a user checks all 3 Checkboxes for example the result shows up in the author box as:

blond brown red

Everthing works fine, but please help me to change my code to achive this result:

blond, brown, red

When i put a "," between the codes it shows me the desired result. BUT if a user 
only checks on checkbox it shows me:

blond,,

I would be very pleased if you would support me :)

Comment: Hi! I read the Stack Overflow questions Checklist again. In the future i will be more careful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php    

    $userarr = array(
            $user_info->new_user_blond,
            $user_info->new_user_brown,
            $user_info->new_user_red,
    );

    $result = implode(',',array_filter($userarr));

    echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thx Kapo - i changed the implode(',' part to implode(', ' to get a space after each output.